# Moving a file through an (powershell created) html button click

Tags: javascript, powershell

We have a powershell script that creates a local html file and the owner of the this script wants to add a button (or something of similar functionality) to the bottom of the html page. When this button is clicked he wants to copy the html document into a new directory.

I created the button, but now I am not sure what I should put in the onclick part of the button.

I don't think IE will recognize powershell commands, and I could use javascript, but putting the javascript into the powershell script seems odd to me.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd or not, that is the way to go. Just have the PS that creates the HTML document also write a javascript onClick event handler in the document as well.

Comment: Okay, so just create a giant string containing the javascript code and the <script> tags and place that in the source of the html page and then have the onclick set to that javascript function?

Comment: Well I don't know how giant it would have to be, but sure.

Comment: Thanks. I am playing with it now. Seems like it will work, just trying to get all the correct javascript syntax within the powershell string.

Comment: Okay, so I have this in my powershell script: